# Application style issue in mobile,Tablet

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, styles

I am working on angular 4 and build an application. Its working fine but the problem is occured when i run it on mobile. Whole style changed And distrub the whole application.I am worried that what i have to do. Any help would be appreciated[image: This is the mobile form]

[image: overlapping is shown in a black box]

[image: This is the orignal Desktop application]

Comment: because your app is not responsive for mobile and tablet

Comment: so how could i make it responsive

Comment: Showing multi-column table in mobile without overlapping or hiding some column is difficult. Have you tried using responsive bootstrap table. Ref https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/responsive/

Comment: No i don't tried nut i think its not the solution

Comment: Tables is not responsive type of layout, so your tables are also non responsive. Easy and clear. Read some tutorials about responsive CSS.

Comment: @MalikRizwan write media Query  for target device and for table [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mohmt5?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) this link is help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take Div before table and Apply div styling `width: 100%;` `overflow: auto;`

```css
.demo {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.demo::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.demo::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #5f6566;
}
.demo::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
<div class="demo">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```